# Flyway executing SQL DDL scripts using Kerberos auth

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, flyway

I have a use case where need to integrate Flyway within application and execute the DDL scripts during application start up which is a normal flyway work of executing the scripts on basis of seeing diff in **schema_version** table.
**The DB used is MSSQL server**

The problem here is when defining the FluentConfiguration and using it in creating Flyway Bean

```
@Bean
    public FluentConfiguration flywayBaseConfiguration() {
        FluentConfiguration configuration = new FluentConfiguration();
        configuration.baselineOnMigrate(true);
        configuration.locations("classpath:com/schemafiles/db_release/DBSQLSERVER");
        configuration.table("schema_version");
        configuration.sqlMigrationPrefix("");
        configuration.sqlMigrationSeparator("UTC-");
        configuration.dataSource(String.format("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:/DBDEVSERVER/TestDB", confManager.getOrThrow(DB_URL))
                , confManager.getOrThrow("db.username"));
        return configuration;
    }

    @Bean
    public Flyway flyway(FluentConfiguration fluentConfiguration) {
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway(fluentConfiguration);
        flyway.migrate();
        return flyway;
    }
```

This fluent config defined above will be used for connecting flyway to DB.

Now if i see the data source connection for the application connecting to prod DB its as follows

```
<bean id="prodDataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="connectionProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="appName">${app.name}</prop>
                <prop key="useKerberos">true</prop>
                <prop key="loginTimeout">${db.login.timeout}</prop>
                <prop key="socketTimeout">${db.socket.timeout}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DBDEVSERVER/TestDB"/>
    </bean>
```

This is using **Kerberos auth in connecting to DB** . We are only providing the user name and rest everything is governed by kerberos security realm.

***The question is does Flyway Fluent Configuration support something related to Kerberos auth in order to be able to execute the DDL scripts without providing the password ??..***

Comment: I believe flyway should work as long as the datasource is valid and connected.

Comment: But the data source needs kerberos auth in SQL Server so how to enable that when setting up Data source for flyway